# PHP Loop mkdir failing

Tags: php

Sorry to bother you with this. I'm running mkdir to replicate directories that I have stored in a DB.

If I display the data on a php page the directories look like this:

```
element1/Content/EPAC/PROD
element1/Content/EPAC/TEST
element1/Content/EPAC_SG/PROD
element1/Content/EU/PROD
element1/Content/EU/TEST
```

The above is a subset of the data. What is happening with the above subset when I loop through it, it creates the directory element1/Content/EPAC/PROD but ignores element1/Content/EPAC/TEST and element1/Content/EPAC_SG/PROD, Then it creates element1/Content/EU/PROD but ignores element1/Content/EU/TEST etc and continues through the loop like that. The code I'm using is:

```
foreach($NSRarray as $value)
{
    mkdir("ftpfolders/$value", 0700, true);
}
```

*the $value variable above is the 'element1/Content/EPAC/PROD' record taken from the DB.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance, Ste

Comment: whats the question and whats the error?

Comment: Did you ever solved the problem ? :) If so please accept the corresponding answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would split this into generating directories one at a time.

Transform your array into sth. like

```
$dics=array(
'element1' => array(
   'Content' => array(
      'EPAC' => array('PROD', 'TEST'),
      'EPAC_SG' => array('PROD')
      'EU' => array('PROD', 'TEST')
     )
   )
);
```

Then loop over it, starting with array_keys($dics) and create the directory if not existing.
Continue with array_keys($dics['element1']) and then repeat it until your reach the inner childs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for answering. I've just actually managed to fix it. Turns out the mkdir after a certain level was adding a space. I did a string replace to remove the space and it created my directories as I would hope. Thank you so much for the intelligent answer though, I'm sure I'll use your idea when I'm stuck again.

Answer (score 1):

use this code, this will gives you proper folder structure as per your requirement

```
<?php
$NSRarray = array('element1/Content/EPAC/PROD', 'element1/Content/EPAC/TEST', 'element1/Content/EPAC_SG/PROD','element1/Content/EU/PROD','element1/Content/EU/TEST');

foreach($NSRarray as $value)
{
    $getFolders = explode('/' , $value);
    $mainFoldername = "ftpfolders";
    $countfolder = 0;
    $countfolder = count($getFolders);
    $tempName = "";
    $i = 0;
    for($i == 0; $i < $countfolder; $i++){
        $tempName .= $getFolders[$i];
         if (!file_exists("$mainFoldername/$tempName")) {
            mkdir("$mainFoldername/$tempName", 0700, true);
        } 
        $tempName .= '/';
    }  
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the reply. I had just managed to fix it already as per the comment above, but I did add your !file_exists to the code, which certainly helped tidy it up. Thanks so much for the reply, hope I can help you out sometime